# Get variables outside of method (object)

Tags: javascript, oop, variables, methods

I am looking to retrieve variables outside a method, but OOP is something new for me, i'm a little stuck ...

```
const Reservation = {
    play: document.getElementById('Reservation'),
    reset: document.getElementById('annuler'),

    launch_functions_sessionStorage: function () {
        this.onReservation();
        this.displayIfChecked();
        this.set_Timer();
    },

    displayIfChecked: function () {
        SOMETHING
    },

    onReservation: function () {
        $('#Reservation, .signature',).click(function () {
            console.log();
            if (SOMETHING) {
                let checked = 1;
            } else {
                let checked = 0;
            }
        });
    },

    set_Timer: function () {

        Reservation.play.addEventListener('click', function(){
            if('I would like to get 'checked'){}
        });
    }
};
Reservation.launch_functions_sessionStorage();
```

I tried to keep important information for your understanding.
Meanwhile sorry for my english...
Thank you very much

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: how can i get my variable checked on set_timer: function ?

Comment: By passing it as a parameter? I am not really sure if I understand the problem here.

Comment: I guess it can solve my problems. Meanwhile i don't know how to call variable outside of method. Just that ^^

Comment: Something like `Reservation.set_time( params... )` ?

Comment: You could declare checked as a field in Reservation. This way it is accessible everywhere in Reservation, so you can set its value in onReservation and read its value in set_Timer.

Comment: javascript is new for me ... sorry i'm not really understand all. Anyway, thank you very much for your help
@mind : thank you !

Comment: could it be that you want to make use of a global variable so you can access it anywhere at all time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
const Reservation = {
    play: document.getElementById('Reservation'),
    reset: document.getElementById('annuler'),

    launch_functions_sessionStorage: function () {
        this.onReservation();
        this.displayIfChecked();
        this.set_Timer();
    },

    displayIfChecked: function () {
        SOMETHING
    },

    onReservation: function () {
        $('#Reservation, .signature',).click(function () {
            console.log();
            if (SOMETHING) {
                let checked = 1;
            } else {
                let checked = 0;
            }
        });
    },
    varThatCanBeCheckedInSetTimer : false,
    set_Timer: function () {
        Reservation.play.addEventListener('click', function(){
            if(varThatCanBeCheckedInSetTimer){
                //your stuff that will happen only if you set varThatCanBeCheckedInSetTimer  to true
             }
        });
    }
};
```

you would use it like

```
Reservation.varThatCanBeCheckedInSetTimer = true;
Reservation.set_Timer();
```

Comment: @LudovicWEBER Glad to help, it is considered nice to acept answer and +1 it ;)